# UNIX time stamp to iso8601 in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to convert a UNIX timestamp into iso8601 format.

for ex:

```
UNIX timestamp "1483050457000"
```

how do I convert it to iso8601 time format in ruby ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require 'time'
Time.at("1483050457000".to_i).iso8601
  #=> "48965-12-30T12:16:40-08:00"
```

`require 'time'` is essential here. Without it you find that you only have access to `Time`'s core methods. Run `Time.instance_methods.sort` to list them. By first executing `require 'time'` the following instance methods are added to the class `Time`: `=> [:httpdate, :iso8601, :rfc2822, :rfc822, :to_date, :to_datetime, :to_time, :xmlschema]`.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be getting your epoch time stamp in the form of a string, so the following will probably be easiest for you:

```
DateTime.strptime("1483050457000",'%s')
```

Note: You seem to have supplied an invalid time stamp in your question, otherwise, I'd have included the output. Try that code with a valid time stamp, and you should get what you want.